# SignalR Monogame Lag

Tags: c#, monogame

I'm creating a C# multiplayer game in Monogame using SignalR to update the enemy players positions.

This is my proxy.invoke:

```
        proxy.Invoke("UpdateEnemy", LocalShip.Position, LocalShip.AngleOfRotation, LocalShip.Id).Wait();
```

The server will take my parameters and send them to the enemies and also take their parameters and send them to me

If I call this method in the Update method the game is extremely laggy.

However if I call it in the Draw method it runs perfectly.

This doesn't seem right to me and I'm wondering does anybody know is there something I'm doing wrong here and why is this happening?

Comment: A good tip in relation to network-messages: Don't send something out in your update-loop. Not directly anyway. Only send out when something changes, such as the player moves, or changes orientation. The reason I'm guessing it makes your update loop laggy, is likely because proxy.Invoke is blocking, so it doesn't return until the message has been received by the server. Why it's NOT making the draw-loop lag though, is a mystery to me. Is the draw-call run on a separate thread perhaps?